# TCL Split string by special character

Tags: list, tcl

I have a string in tcl say:

```
set name "a_b_c_d"
```

and I want to get 4 variables out of it like $a would have the value, $b the value b, etc...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Do you mean that if you have a string `x_y_z` that you want to get 3 variables named `x`, `y` and `z` respectively and each containing the strings `x`, `y` and `z` respectively?

Comment: @Jerry, yes exactly. I understand the split but I'm unsure on how I should separate and store in different variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the `split` command is for. You just need to provide the optional argument that says what character to use to split the string into a list of its fields.

```
set fields [split $name "_"]
```

Note that if you have two of the split character in a row, you get an empty list element in the result.

Comment: You _can_ specify multiple split characters, but that's probably a bad idea most of the time as it splits on _any_ of them and you consequently lose information. For more sophisticated string splitting, use `regexp -inline -all` or Tcllib's splitting commands; they work differently though.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit strange in my opinion, but that's how I would do it:

```
set name a_b_c_d
foreach item [split $name "_"] {
    set $item $item
}
```

You didn't ask for the following, but I believe it might be better if you use an array, so you know exactly where your variables are, instead of just being 'there' in the open:

```
set name a_b_c_d
foreach item [split $name "_"] {
    set items($item) $item
}

parray items
# items(a) = a
# items(b) = b
# items(c) = c
# items(d) = d
```

---

EDIT: Since you mentioned it in a comment, I'll just put it here: if the situation is as you mentioned, I'd probably go like this:

```
lassign [split $name "_"] varName folderName dirName
```

And it should still work most of the time. Dynamic variable names are not recommended and can 90% of the time be avoided for a safer, more readable and maintainable code. Sure, it works for things that you just need once in a blue moon, but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you Jerry ! The idea is that I have a file name which is created based on a variablename_foldername_directoryname, and I need to extract folder name and directory name, therefore needed to split based on "_" but also keeping the folder name and directory name into a variable which I can re-use later on. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry ! Just that extra line solved my issue ;) I'll remember the lassign from now.